# Script Component - ODBC exception password incorrect - package validation

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, filemaker, ssis-2012

I'm trying to insert some rows into Filemaker using Script Component. I followed this article [Creating an ODBC Destination with the Script Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting-data-flow-script-component-examples/creating-an-odbc-destination-with-the-script-component)

When I edit the script  here I set the connection string:

```
public override void AcquireConnections(object Transaction)
{

    string connectionString;
    //connectionString = this.Connections.FmConnection.ConnectionString;
    odbcConn = new OdbcConnection("uid=someUID;Dsn=FM;pwd=somepassword");
    odbcConn.Open();

}
```

I get the connection string from the this.Connections object and set it to the new OdbcConnection object. This does not work as I keep getting the exception. I tried setting the connection string manually as you can see above. I still get the exception.

In other parts of my package I use the connection manager to Filemaker and it works. Just not in this script component.

The exceptions I'm getting is:

> Error at MyPackageName: [Filemaker] Password Incorrect

What is wrong?

Comment: Did some research.  Are your DSNs for FileMaker defined at the User or System level?  Defined in both 32-bit and 64-bit DSN?  Seems that the script component can have trouble accessing them.  Have a look at [this post](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2012/03/08/odbc-in-ssis-2012.aspx) from Jamie Thomson.

Comment: I played around with it some more and somehow got it to work. I created the DSNs at the System level. Thanks for the article. It's useful.